# CircleCI Docker ECR orb ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/init.sh" not found

Tags: docker, circleci

I am utilizing CircleCI and ECR orb to build my docker image and push it to Elastic Container Registry ( ECR ) but I keep running into the following error: `ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/init.sh" not found`.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
Terraform
  .circleci
  infra
  frontend
    --- Dockerfile
    --- init.sh
```

So basically I have a Terraform directory. Inside that directory I have an `infra` directory and a `frontend` directory. The frontend directory consists of my `Dockerfile` and my `init.sh` script.

The contents of my Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM node:14
ENV JQ_VERSION=1.6
RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-${JQ_VERSION}/jq-linux64 -O /tmp/jq-linux64
RUN cp /tmp/jq-linux64 /usr/bin/jq
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/jq
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN jq 'to_entries | map_values({ (.key) : ("$" + .key) }) | reduce .[] as $item ({}; . + $item)' ./src/config.json > ./src/config.tmp.json && mv ./src/config.tmp.json ./src/config.json
RUN npm install && npm run build

FROM nginx:1.17
ENV JSFOLDER=/usr/share/nginx/html/js/*.js
COPY ./init.sh /usr/bin/init.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/init.sh
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=0 /app/dist .
ENTRYPOINT [ "init.sh" ]
```

and my CircleCI config has the following content:

```
version: '2.1'
orbs:
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@8.2.1
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@3.1
jobs:
  build:
    machine:
      image: ubuntu-2004:2022.10.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          repo: frontend
          push-image: true
          region: ${AWS_REGION}
          registry-id: REGISTRY_ID
          dockerfile: frontend/Dockerfile
          path: .
          tag: ${CIRCLE_SHA1}
workflows:
  test:
    jobs:
      - build:
```

But CircleCI gives me the following error:

```
> [stage-1 2/5] COPY ./init.sh /usr/bin/init.sh:
------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/init.sh" not found: not found

Exited with code exit status 1
```

Comment: What is your **specific** question? What part of the error message is not clear to you? Have you tried `COPY ./frontend/init.sh /usr/bin/init.sh`?

Comment: @hakre bro you're the man. If you post this below, i'll accept the answer.

Comment: done. and if you follow some of it, you can ask better questions about the unknowns here on SO next time (let me know if its good to read/understand as its more of an article).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires reading and understanding of the error message (and yes a little bit of discipline if it is all-new as we're easily distracted in complex computer systems):

```
> ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/init.sh" not found: not found
```

The message result is at the end, the operation in front, separator is `:`. Additionally the message is prefixed by its class (`ERROR`).

More structural:

### Error: failed to solve

1. failed to compute cache key
2. "/init.sh" not found
3. not found

If you're coming from development, compare it a bit with a backtrace, but you need to throw a bit more brain on it as we don't have file paths and line numbers (not even binary offsets) here.

For me for example, it is that 2. and 3. tell me "not found" is a file not found. As this is within Dockerfile (or Docker build) context, we can spot one operation already, as we know it involves files and a real file-system that could give such I/O errors:

```
COPY ./init.sh /usr/bin/init.sh
```

Then I'd read-up the manual for `COPY` <sup>1</sup> to understand a bit better why the message tells it is `/init.sh` (absolute path) while within the `COPY` directive it is `./init.sh` (relative path). I may not understand it within three minutes therefore I skip with this knowledge and know that I only assume it is a match.

Then given it is a match I look into its circelci binding:

```
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          repo: frontend
          push-image: true
          region: ${AWS_REGION}
          registry-id: REGISTRY_ID
          dockerfile: frontend/Dockerfile
          path: .
          tag: ${CIRCLE_SHA1}
```

Again, we need to get into the know and that is finding the reference for the  CircleCI Orb and its command in question: `aws-ecr/build-and-push-image`<sup>2</sup>. Without it, we have no reference and aren't able to gather any meaning (just to guess it, but who needs brute force all the time? The strong weak!).

As our first assumption is this is file-system related we can perhaps identify the *`dockerfile`* and *`path`*:

> **`dockerfile`**: Name of dockerfile to use. Defaults to Dockerfile.
>
> ```
> REQUIRED: No    DEFAULT: Dockerfile    TYPE: string
> ```
>
> **`path`**: Path to the directory containing your Dockerfile. Defaults to . (working
> directory).
>
> ```
> REQUIRED: No    DEFAULT: .             TYPE: string
> ```

You then lay all those three piece of information one after another:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/init.sh" not found: not found

COPY ./init.sh /usr/bin/init.sh

dockerfile: frontend/Dockerfile
path: .
```

Comparing this information against the actual project file layout, the cause of error is now relatively easy to spot: there is no such file `./init.sh`.

And it is now relatively easy to bind the correct path, as we knew it from the beginning:

```
COPY ./frontend/init.sh /usr/bin/init.sh
```

Learn on how to treat error messages with respect, they have a story to tell, despite how bad/or hard to read they may appear, always remember it is the best you'll get. And I always look up the references. If I dunno where the reference is at least (and expressing that knowledge with a URL is reasonable adequate for distributed systems), I'm often doing the wrong step first. It must not that I fully understand the system, but I need to know about what I know and what I not know about so I can slow down the moving target that decided to ran away and giving us an error at least. Trouble shooting 1x1.

And as we have all parts under version control here (if you don't, do that first), those hypertext references are easy to add to the commit message, which should document the driver of the change (the error message) and how we think the change addresses it (and *c.f. [Beams](https://web.archive.org/web/20140903140310/http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit)*):

- original error message
- git reference since when it was introduced
- and fix attempt rationale

And just a final note: When we have fixed the error, it is easy (or easier) to say what the cause was. So in the moment of the commit and putting it to test, we can only document our little understanding. However it is important to at least document it so that even steep learning curves can be taken without loosing track and going in all fresh each time of an error in (remote) CI. Feedback is too often slow to waste time with staying in the unknown. You should always only apply a fix by having the rationale of it *a priori*, with perhaps the exclusion that if it takes longer than three minutes - which in remote CI means it must be a single commit that did run through and was tested working within that three minutes time if you want to make a good rule of thumb out of it <sup>3</sup>.

> COPY that .

TLDR: [CircleCI Docker ECR orb ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/init.sh" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75978979/circleci-docker-ecr-orb-error-failed-to-solve-failed-to-compute-cache-key-i?noredirect=1#comment134006069_75978979)

---

1. **COPY** Dockerfile reference https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy
2. **aws-ecr/build-and-push-image** CircleCI Orb https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/aws-ecr#commands-build-and-push-image
3. I sadly don't have the reference for the three minute guess-time in debugging at hand, basically how I understand it here it means you should not guess longer than only a short time (like 3 minutes) while debugging but answer all your own questions before you question the system or others that configured it (asking for help is fine, cooperation is key). Also there is the **Golden Rule** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Rule.

- [[Beams](https://web.archive.org/web/20140903140310/http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit)]: [Chris Beams, How to Write a Git Commit Message, 31 Aug 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20140903140310/http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit)

Comment: some more links for commit messages: https://gist.github.com/julienbourdeau/e605e4b8b47da97c249a0f72598529c8 including https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project#Commit-Guidelines